# What WinAPI mechanism "automatically" destroys an owned window?

Tags: windows, winapi, window

Documentation describes these behaviors of [owned windows](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows):

> - An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.
> - The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is
>     destroyed.
> - An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.

I observe the first and third behaviors to work exactly as described, but I haven't yet observed the second. The mechanism for automatic destruction seems opaque so I don't know how to debug it. No relevant message (`WM_QUIT`, `WM_DESTROY`, `WM_NCDESTROY`) is sent to the message loop of the owned window after the owner window is closed/destroyed, so I'm also not sure how I would even handle this behavior.

It is worth noting that I *can* manually destroy the owned window in response to the owner window's destruction, using an event hook listening for `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY`. However, this leaves a sour taste in my mouth since it feels like a workaround to an insiduous bug in my code.

Comment: Are you looping in the message loop? Certainly `WM_DESTROY` is a sent message and you won't see it inside the message loop.

Comment: You state that *"no relevant message [...] is sent to the message loop of the owned window"*. That confuses me. A message loop isn't associated with a window. It's associated with a thread. Does your owned window live on a thread that's different from the owning window's?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, they're on separate threads. The owning window isn't mine.

Comment: So the owning window is in a different process?

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) You broke the rules, but *"you must first become the master of the rules before you can start breaking them"*.

Comment: Thank you both, I have enough food for thought now ^^;

Comment: hi, have your issue been solved?